# Program not calculating probabilities correctly

Tags: java, algorithm

Edit: One bug was found. Wrong testcases updated

I have a program in which it rolls five dice and assigns a hand to the rolls. i.e. nothing, a pair, two pair, three of a kind, full house,  four of a kind, five of a kind. The code runs 1000000 times and gives percetage chances for each roll. Below I have attatched general percentages my code should output near:

```
Case 1, None alike, is 0.092533
Case 2, One pair, is 0.462799
Case 3, Two pair, is 0.231789
Case 4, Three of a kind, is 0.154192
Case 5, Full house, is 0.038595
Case 6, Four of a kind, is 0.019316
Case 7, Five of a kind, is 0.000776
```

However my code gives the following output:

```
Case 1, None alike is 7.57E-4
Case 2, One pair is 0.019422
Case 3, Two pair is 0.270331
Case 4, Three of a kind is 0.153657
Case 5, Full House is 0.270331
Case 6, Four of a kind is 0.019422
Case 7, Five of a kind is7.57E-4
```

I don't understand why my programs percentages are so off. They don't even add up to one. I have gone through and tested my logic but it is sound from what I have seen. I would appreciate another set of eyes to take a look and let me know if they could catch somehting of. Below is my code:

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you see this statement?

```java
     else if (rolled [i] == 5) {
                six++;
     }
```

in your counts method?  It may be contributing to the problem.

Edit:

You're not printing the correct variables.  The I've pointed  to the ones that are incorrect.

```java
        System.out.println("Case 1, None alike is "+fivep); <---- should be 'none'
        System.out.println("Case 2, One pair is "+fourp);   <---- should be 'pair'
        System.out.println("Case 3, Two pair is "+full);   <---- should be  'twop'
        System.out.println("Case 4, Three of a kind is "+threep); 
        System.out.println("Case 5, Full House is "+full);
        System.out.println("Case 6, Four of a kind is "+fourp);
        System.out.println("Case 7, Five of a kind is"+fivep);
```

Once I made the changes your probabilities came out really close to the expected.

Answer (score -2):

Have You considered that java.lang.Math.random() method returns a pseudorandom (double) greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0? What about using java.security.SecureRandom object for that purpose? A suggestion:

```
import java.security.SecureRandom
// ...
secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
// ...
for (int i = 0; i<=1000000; i++)
{
     int [] rolls = new int[5];
     rolls[0] = secureRandom.nextInt(6) + 1; // secureRandom.nextInt(6) picks a number from the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} at random
     rolls[1] = secureRandom.nextInt(6) + 1;         
     // ...
```

Comment: How would this change solve any of th problems I am currently having?

Comment: Have You considered that You are casting to int the elements of the rolls array prior to assigning them and that there exists type conversion from to the original random() method (which returns a double)? Are not You counting dice outcomes within the Counts() method? So, if outcomes are being influenced by the type conversion, it can be the case that counting them also becomes influenced. Can't be?

Comment: Besides not addressing the question, the code in this answer isn't syntactically correct. If `secureRandom` is an object then you cannot call it as if it is a method.

Comment: Of course You are correct. I meant secureRandom.nextInt(6). Thanks a lot.